# "undeclared identifier" in Vim. But this is not an identifier

Tags: ubuntu, vim, cmake, vtk, youcompleteme

I am usingVim with YouCompleteMe(plugin).
My OS is Ubuntu 16.04. My shell is Z shell(zsh).

The code below is a vtk example.(from [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/GeometricObjects/Cylinder))

[image: Cylinder.cpp Vim Capture]

> #### Problem
>
> That 'cylinderSource' is declared on line 13.
> However, an error occurred in line 14.
>
> The msg is " use of undeclared identifier 'cylinderSource' ".
>
> The compiling this code works perfectly well, but vim does not autocomplete and that red is annoying me.

Here's my code:

**ycm_extra_conf.py**

```
flags = [
...
# VTK
'-I/hdd1/Install/VTK/VTK_sources/Common/Core',
'-I/hdd1/Install/VTK/VTK_sources/Common/DataModel',
'-I/hdd1/Install/VTK/VTK_sources/Filters/Sources',
'-I/hdd1/Install/VTK/VTK_sources/Rendering/Core',
...
]
compilation_database_folder = '~/.vim/'
```

(The compile_commands.json is in '~/.vim' by build.sh)

**~/.zshrc(Similar to bashrc)**

```
...
export VTK_DIR='/opt/VTK'
...
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
PROJECT(Cylinder)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

add_executable(Cylinder MACOSX_BUNDLE Cylinder)

if(VTK_LIBRARIES)
  target_link_libraries(Cylinder ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
else()
  target_link_libraries(Cylinder vtkHybrid vtkWidgets)
endif()
```

**build.sh**

```
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON ..
cp compile_commands.json ~/.vim/
make -j4
cd ..
```

Comment: Tip: Better use IDE with a vim emulator plug in installed.

Comment: Thanks. now I am using vscode.